# Unable to install turtlebot

Tags: ros, gazebo, turtlebot, ros-lunar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) and installed ROS Lunar. I also installed gazebo7. Now, I want to install turtlebot and it's impossible. This is what I did:

I followed all the tutorials about the installation, but after running this:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch
```

I get the following error:

```
RLException: [turtlebot_world.launch] is neither a launch file in package [turtlebot_gazebo] nor is [turtlebot_gazebo] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Internet doesn't help. I did everything that says there and nothing works. I also did this:

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
```

before running the other command line. And it doesn't work.

What can I do? Maybe my problem is that I have ROS Lunar and I install kinetic packages, but the tutorials are (almost everyone) for indigo.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282487/unable-to-install-turtlebot/) by [Dylan](https://answers.ros.org/users/31995/dylan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2018-02-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-12**:\

> I did everything that says there and nothing works

What *specifically* did you do and what *specifically* happened? Also, did you `source` your workspace (i.e., `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`)?

**Comment by [Dylan](https://answers.ros.org/users/31995/dylan/) on 2018-02-12**:
@jayess It doesn't work:

> source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash

> roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch

Gives the same error as before:

> RLException: ...

I installed everything as: http://sauravag.com/2016/10/how-to-setup-turtlebot-simulator-in-ros-with-gazebo/ for example

**Comment by [Dylan](https://answers.ros.org/users/31995/dylan/) on 2018-02-15**:
@jayess Do you know what can I do? I really need this working. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You do not appear to have the package `turtlebot_gazebo` installed. There's a comment at the bottom of the blog mentioning what looks like you need to install slightly different packages including `ros-indigo-turtlebot-gazebo`.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1